# Split text by sentences | Custom

Tags: php, preg-split

I have a function to slit text by sentences:

```
public static function getSentences($str) {
    return preg_split('/(?<=[.?!;:])\s+/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

But find a problem:

> The object passed Mars's orbit around Nov. 1 and will pass Jupiter's
>   orbit in May of 2018.
>   It will travel beyond Saturn's orbit in January 2019; as it leaves our solar system, 'Oumuamua will head for the constellation Pegasus.

The function above split this text in four sentences. (After: ...Nov. ; ...2019;);

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Language processing is hard. Consider to use a pre-made library, like https://research.googleblog.com/2016/05/announcing-syntaxnet-worlds-most.html or http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/ or http://php-nlp-tools.com

Comment: Maybe any other way by php and mind :)?